# What does this group of numbers represent?

Tags: number-sequence

How is this set of 8 numbers - $6, 8, 15, 20, 36, 48, 90$, and $120$ - derived?

I could provide hints but it would make it too easy.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't know if it is the right solution, but if we consider:

> a die

Then I got this explanation:

> Roll a die in front of you. You should see three sides, like this:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Now, multiply the numbers appearing on the three faces. You should get a number between $6$ and $120$.
>  In fact, **there are only 8 possibilities**: the ones in the sequence.
>  Why? Because, if you see a number $x$, $1 \le x\le 6$, then you **can't** see the number $7-x$, because it is on the opposite side.
>  So if we list all the possible products obtained from multiplying three numbers on a die, and if we cross out the non-obtainable ones, we get the following list :
>
>  $1*2*3 = 6$
>  $1*2*4 = 8$
>  <s>1*2*5 = 10</s>
>  <s>1*2*6 = 12</s> 
>  <s>1*3*4 = 12</s> 
>  $1*3*5 = 15$
>  <s>1*3*6 = 18</s> 
>  $1*4*5 = 20$
>  <s>1*4*6 = 24</s> 
>  <s>1*5*6 = 30</s> 
>  <s>2*3*4 = 24</s> 
>  <s>2*3*5 = 30</s> 
>  $2*3*6 = 36$
>  <s>2*4*5 = 40</s> 
>  $2*4*6 = 48$
>  <s>2*5*6 = 60</s> 
>  <s>3*4*5 = 60</s> 
>  <s>3*4*6 = 72</s> 
>  $3*5*6 = 90$
>  $4*5*6 = 120$
>
>  And of course, you will recognize the sequence in the question. Plus, this sequence is finite.

Comment: Nice! It explains, why something like x/(7-x) appeared in the formula I've found, and also why there is a binary-like symmetry.

Comment: @elias Exactly! Thanks for correcting the typo by the way :)

Comment: "a die" is the singular of "two dice"

Comment: Neat. It explains how come their LCM is $720=6!$.

Comment: @trentcl Yes, thank you. I was not sure : https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dice. It states that *in modern standard English dice is both the singular and the plural: throw the dice could mean a reference to either one or more than one dice*

Comment: @IAmInPLS Huh. For something that is "modern standard English", I've never seen "a dice" in print (board game manuals, for example, pretty much unanimously use "a die"). Maybe it's a British/American split. I would still recommend using "a die". [A question about this on english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167104/singular-of-dice)

Comment: @RosieF, yep. Earlier I furthermore noticed that 6*120=8*90=15*48=20*36=6!, but I could not figure out anything with that.

Comment: This right! I was wondering if I should make this a puzzle - YOUR ANSWER ENCOUREGED ME! Thanks - of course you get the V

Answer (score 7):

If we note them as

> $a_0=6$, $a_1=8$, and so on,

they match the formula:

> $a_n=a_{n-b_n}\times\frac{4+\log_2b_n}{3-\log_2b_n}$, where $b_n$ is the largest possible power of two, which divides $n$

For example:

> $n=4$: $b_n=4$
>  $a_4=a_{4-4}\times\frac{4+2}{3-2}=a_0\times\frac61=36$

Comment: Does this limit it to 8 values?

Comment: it does, as calculating the next term would include a division by 0

Comment: I understand now. The series is derived in a different way.

Comment: could you elaborate on why this does not work? maybe by adding some of the next terms in your sequence?

Comment: I am not claiming this will not work - what I claim that the answer is much more simple and requires more an observation than high math. To every finite set of numbers you could find a solution which will fit if the set is based on some simple rules - may be if you will look into why what you did fits you might see some other features that will lead you to the solution. If in a week there will not be an answer, will provide then hint(s).

Comment: Ok. I'm interested in the solution you have in mind and how it is related to the formula I gave: if it is a purely accidental match, or one being a direct conclusion of the other. I will wait for the hints patiently.

Comment: how the hell this answer matches the other answer?

Comment: @Santropedro, well, $a_0=6$ is the 'default' product $1\times2\times3$. If you see $4$ instead of $3$, the product changes to $a_0\times\frac43$. Also you can see $5$ instead of $2$ (that's another factor of \frac52), and $6$ instead of $1$ (factor \frac61). All these factors can be present indepently from each other, so digits of binary representation of numbers in the range $[0; 7]$ can be used to describe which factors are active.